# Role of clustering algorithms in semantic segmentation pipeline?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, cluster-analysis, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I'm trying to think of ways in which clustering (e.g. k-means) fits into procedures for doing semantic segmentation or object recognition on images. My understanding is that semantic segmentation is done principally using deep CNNs. K-means works fine for segmentation, but semantic segmentation is supervised, thus makes clustering itself insufficient.

My question is: how can such unsupervised techniques fit into the overall pipeline of semantic segmentation? Do other techniques generally dominate it, or are there still practical use cases for problems involving classification/localization? I'm aware of a [paper using k-means clustering to generate candidate boxes](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=9113676) – are there other relevant use cases of clustering techniques in this pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

They do not dominate but are used when data is less.

Unsupervised methods are used in medical image segmentation where data is generally scarce.

Example - Hill Climbing Segmentation
Implementation: https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22274-hill-climbing-color-image-segmentation

[image]

Have a look at this [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7583961) for a discussion on hill climbing and k-means for segmentation